# Updating model and Child deletes Grandchild :( Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have:

Initial_application.rb

```
has_one :full_application
has_one :statement, through: :full_application
accepts_nested_attributes_for :application_status
accepts_nested_attributes_for :full_application
```

Full_application.rb

```
has_one :statement
has_one :plaid_auth, through: :statement
```

Statement.rb

```
has_many_attached :files
belongs_to :full_application, optional: true
```

So I have 
- initial_application
- full_application (child of initial_application)
- statement (child of full_application, therefore grandchild of initial_application)

initial_application_controller.rb

```
def edit_full
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
  render layout: 'fullapplication_layout'
  end
end
```

I created an action in the controller to update initial application and full_application. Created a nested form etc, put in the strong params etc.

```
def initial_application_params
  params.require(:initial_application).permit( :source, :amount, :years, :sales, :creditscore, :email, :name, :phone, :interest, :businessname, application_status_attributes: [:status, :person, :status_name, :status_description, :status_note], full_application_attributes: [:amount, :years, :sales, :creditscore, :email, :phone, :name, :defaults, :existingach, :acceptcc, :seasonal, :balance, :lender, :interest, :street, :apt, :city, :state, :zipcode, :businessname, :bstreet, :bapt, :bcity, :bstate, :bzipcode, :dba, :legalentity, :fedtaxid, :dob, :percentage, :own, :bown, :bphone, :analytics, :source, :credit_auth, :ip ] )
end
```

edit_full_form.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @initial_application do |f| %>
...
<%= f.simple_fields_for :application_status do |p| %>
...
<% end %> 
<%= f.simple_fields_for :full_application do |m| %>
...
<% end %>
<%= f.button :submit, "Update Status", class: "button is-medium" %>
<% end %>
```

But when I update initial_application and full_application with the nested form it deletes statement. I figured the problem, but I don't know how to fix that.

"Update" action is creating a new full_application record and not updating the old full_application.

Comment: How do you update it? Show the action of the controller which processes your POST request to update.

Comment: regular 
def update
@initial_application.update(initial_application_params)
end
Great comment Ilya, just found out it creates a new record for full_application when I update initial_application. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full_aplication record is being recreated because you do not pass its `id`. As the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-many) says:

> For each hash that does *not* have an `id` key a new record will be instantiated, unless the hash also contains a `_destroy` key that evaluates to `true`.

To fix it you need to add an `:id` to the nested list of permitted params `full_application_attributes`, and pass that ID to the form as a hidden_field.

Comment: You are a genius Iluha!